# Many-to-Many MySQL Relationship

Tags: mysql

Good Morning,

I'm after some help please :)
I have a MySQL database with the following tables: `incidents`, `users` and `incident_users`.

My `incidents` and `users` table are defined through a many-to-many relationship using the `incident_users` table.

So, when a user adds an incident, the incident_id and user_id are captured. It is possible for an incident_id to be associated with multiple user_id.

I'm looking to return a result like so:

| incident_id | user_fullname |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith |
| 2 | Jane Doe & John Smith |
| 3 | Robert Doe |

Where user_fullname is a column from the `users` table and the grouping by incident_id

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be slightly vague as you have not shared the full details of your tables. But the basic idea should be along the lines of :

```
select incident_id, group_concat(user_name separator ' & ') as user_fullname ... group by incident_id
```

See also: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `incident_users` table is made up of a `incident_id` and a `user_id`

then its a simple case of using the `incident_id` from this table and JOINing it to the `User` table

```
SELECT i.incident_id, u.user_fullname
FROM incident i
    LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = i.user_id
```

If you have a `firstname` and `lastname` column but no `fullname` column, you can build a concatenation of the 2 you have as part of the query like this

```
SELECT i.incident_id, CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) as user_fullname
FROM incident i
    LEFT JOIN user u ON u.id = i.user_id
```